# re-render react component after i deleted from local storage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I have 2 components. Display and DisplayList. Components work together to display values from local storage. Everything works fine. However When I activate handleDelete method. Values are deleted from local storage but react doesn't re-render list.

Summary: I want for react to re render my displayValues after I activate method handleDelete()

[Github Link](https://github.com/ArnasDickus/enigma-assignment)

Display.JSX

```
import {DisplayList} from './DisplayList';


class Display extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: data,
  }

  // Methods
  this.displayValues = this.displayValues.bind(this);
  }

  displayValues(){
   return this.state.data.map((data1, index) =>
    <DisplayList
      key = {index}
      email = {data1.email}
      password = {data1.password}
       /> 
    )

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="list-group">
        {this.displayValues()}
      </ul>
    )

  }
}
```

DisplayList.JSX

```
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';


export class DisplayList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)


        // Methods
        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    }


    handleDelete(){
        const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
        for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
            if(this.props.email === data[index].email &&
                this.props.password === data[index].password){
                data.splice(data[index], 1);
            }
        }
        localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
    }

  render() {
    return (
    <div className = "mt-4">
        <li className="list-group-item text-justify">
            Email: {this.props.email} 
            <br /> 
            Password: {this.props.password}
            <br /> 
            <Button variant = "info mr-4 mt-1">Edit</Button>
            <Button onClick = {this.handleDelete} variant = "danger mt-1">Delete</Button>
        </li>  
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: When deleting from `localStorage`, also remove the item from state in `Display`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way you could achieve this is by sending down a callback function as a `prop` from `Display.JSX` to `DisplayList.JSX`. And from `handleDelete`, trigger the callback to the parent and set the state in it. Sample code follows.

Display.jsx

```
import {DisplayList} from './DisplayList';


class Display extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: data,
  }

  // Methods
  this.displayValues = this.displayValues.bind(this);
  }

  displayValues(){
   return this.state.data.map((data1, index) =>
    <DisplayList
      key = {index}
      email = {data1.email}
      password = {data1.password}
      updateList = {this.updateList}
       /> 
    )

  }
  // This is the method that will be called from the child component.
  updateList = (data) => {
    this.setState({
      data
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="list-group">
        {this.displayValues()}
      </ul>
    )

  }
}
```

DisplayList.jsx

```
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';


export class DisplayList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)


        // Methods
        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    }


    handleDelete(){
        const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
        for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
            if(this.props.email === data[index].email &&
                this.props.password === data[index].password){
                data.splice(data[index], 1);
            }
        }
        localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
        this.props.updateList(data);
    }

  render() {
    return (
    <div className = "mt-4">
        <li className="list-group-item text-justify">
            Email: {this.props.email} 
            <br /> 
            Password: {this.props.password}
            <br /> 
            <Button variant = "info mr-4 mt-1">Edit</Button>
            <Button onClick = {this.handleDelete} variant = "danger mt-1">Delete</Button>
        </li>  
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like accepted answer and you can have other way to do this also, like below:

Moved your `handleDelete` event in `Parent` itself, where your state `data` is there.

```
 class Display extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        data: data || [{email: 'j', password: "dsv" }],
    }
  }


    handleDelete(email, password){
        const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
        data = data ? data : this.state.data
        for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
            if(email === data[index].email &&
                password === data[index].password){
                data.splice(data[index], 1);
            }
        }
        localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
        this.setState({data});
    }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state)
    debugger
    return (
      <ul className="list-group">
        {this.state.data.map((data1, index) =>
          <DisplayList
            key = {index}
            email = {data1.email}
            password = {data1.password}
            handleDelete = {() => this.handleDelete(data1.email,data1.password )}
            /> 
          )}
      </ul>
    )

  }
}
```

and in `DisplayList`

```
    export default class DisplayList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }


  render() {
    return (
    <div className = "mt-4">
        <li className="list-group-item text-justify">
            Email: {this.props.email} 
            <br /> 
            Password: {this.props.password}
            <br /> 
            <Button variant = "info mr-4 mt-1">Edit</Button>
            <Button onClick = {this.props.handleDelete} variant = "danger mt-1">Delete</Button>
        </li>  
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jwdmxt)

Comment: Your solution also works. Can't say which one is better.

Comment: @ArnasDičkus If you don't do other than delete you can keep handleDelete in Parent itself, else you can follow Harsha Venkatram's answer